# SwifMailer setBcc or setTo not working

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Here is my code:

```
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
    ->setSender('my email id', 'my name')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'AppBundle:Mail:email.html.twig',
            array('result' => $result)
        ),
        'text/html'
);

$message->setTo(array($customerEmail => 'jhon doe'));
$message->setBcc(array($clientEmail => 'jhon doe 1'));
$mailer->send($message)`
```

This is another implementation of the same code

```
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
    ->setSender('my email id', 'my name')
    ->setTo(array($customerEmail => 'jhon doe'))
    ->addBcc($clientEmail, 'jhon doe 1')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'AppBundle:Mail:email.html.twig',
            array('result' => $result)
        ),
        'text/html'
    );
```

In both the cases either `setTo()` or `setBcc()` works but both combined are not working, can anyone help me with this it would be of great help.

I'm using gmail as the mail server, I have tried both the configuration for ssl and tls.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? The email is sent to only one of these mail addresses? Have you tried setting the same email address for both fields and check if 2 emails arrive in the inbox? Can you show the transport settings (without sensitive data like password and username)?

Comment: when i use setTo and setBcc togother or one after another,  only one of them sends the mails and the other will not send the mail

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand. When does it not send the mail? Also how do you know it is not sent? Is there an error?

Comment: No there was no error. but I get to know that the mail is not sent by giving the mail id's which I know of. and checking the inbox of those mail id's. I received the mail's only for either setTo() or setBcc() which ever is executed first. and not the other one.

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe you must use setBcc once before you can use addBcc. It appears to me in your 2nd example that you're using addBcc without a setBcc prior to it. If I am correct, this could be part of the trouble you're experiencing. I too am having similar issues but not exactly as you've described yours. Mine seems to be an inability to use addBcc with email=>name arrays. Using addBcc with only email addresses, however, seems to work as expected.